# PHP: How to preload assets in head?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using two Google fonts and I'm looking to preload those assets, rather than enqueuing them so that they're not flagged in Page Speed Insights.

When I enqueue the fonts, the fonts load correctly. This works:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'poppins', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,700&display=swap' );
```

However, when I preload the assets and hook into `wp_head`, the fonts do not load. This doesn't work (in `functions.php`):

```
<?php

function preload_assets() {

    $font_1 = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,700&display=swap";
    $font_2 = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Serif:ital,opsz,wght@0,8..144,300;0,8..144,400;1,8..144,200&display=swap";

    // connect to domain of font files
    $preload = '<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>';

    // optionally increase loading priority
    $preload .= '<link rel="preload" as="style" href="'.$font_1.'">
    <link rel="preload" as="style" href="'.$font_2.'">';


    // async CSS
      $preload .= '<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.onload=null;this.removeAttribute('."media".');" href="'.$font_1.'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.onload=null;this.removeAttribute('."media".');" href="'.$font_2.'">';

    // no-JS fallback
    $preload .= '<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$font_1.'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$font_2.'">
    </noscript>';

    echo $preload;

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'preload_assets' );
```

Why is this? Upon inspecting the source code, I can see the font files being referenced correctly, but the font doesn't show on the front end?

Comment: Can you try changing your onload to just `onload="this.media='all'"`. Also, in your network tools do you see the CSS files getting downloaded?

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas - I changed and tested `onload="this.media='all'"` - the issue still persisted (no changes). I can confirm that both fonts show as downloaded in networks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the [Plugin API/Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), `wp_enqueue_scripts` is triggered before `wp_head` which is why.

You should use the [`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) hook filter which filters the HTML script tag of an enqueued script.

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {

    $fonts = array(
        array(
            'handle' => 'google-fonts-popins',
            'url' => 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,700&display=swap',
        ),
        array(
            'handle' => 'google-fonts-roboto',
            'url' => 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Serif:ital,opsz,wght@0,8..144,300;0,8..144,400;1,8..144,200&display=swap',
        ),
    );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $fonts as $font ) {
        $i++;

        wp_enqueue_style( $font['handle'], $font['url'], array(), 'all' );

        add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle, $href, $media ) use ( $font, $i ) {
        
            if ( $font['handle'] === $handle ) {
    
                $tag = str_replace(
                    'media="all">',
                    'media="all"><link rel="preload" as="style" href="' . $href . '">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.onload=null;this.removeAttribute(\'media\');" href="' . $href . '">
                    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $href . '"></noscript>',
                    $tag
                );

                if ( 1 === $i ) {

                    $tag .= '<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
                    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>';

                };
    
            };
    
            return $tag;
    
        }, 10, 4 );

    };

} );
```

Comment: I see, wasn't aware `wp_enqueue_scripts` is triggered before `wp_head`. I ported over the above snippet and it seems like only the first font in the `array` is rendered on the front end. The 2nd font is not visible upon inspect. The php in the snippet isn't being rendered in the output as on inspect, I see `id="google-fonts-{$i}-css"` - full output here: `<link rel="stylesheet" id="google-fonts-{$i}-css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins%3Aital%2Cwght%400%2C400%3B0%2C600%3B0%2C700%3B1%2C700&amp;display=swap&amp;ver=all" type="text/css" media="all">`

Comment: Additionally, I did a `var_dump($handle);` and it outputted `string(11) "jquery-core" string(11) "jquery-core”` - this can’t be correct, right?

Comment: With the new snippet, I'm getting an `undefined variable: font` error on this line: `if ( $font['handle'] === $handle )`. What is the purpose of this `if statement` btw? For example, `if("google-fonts-popins" === "google-fonts-popins")` - this will always be true, so what is it's purpose?

Comment: A `var_dump($font)` straight after the `foreach` does print the array successfully. Just isn't recognising it in the if statement

Comment: I think we're getting there, slowly. With the latest snippet, the `closure` function is now throwing a `Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function ` error (on line: `add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle, $href, $media ) use ( $font, $i ) {`). Other closures seem to have similar amounts of arguments (i.e. `function ($quantity) use ($tax, &$total) { .. };`) and seem to be working. So unsure why the error is cropping up here?

Comment: `}, 10, 3 );` change it to `}, 10, 4 );`

Comment: Can confirm, that did the trick :) much appreciated for the help and for this reusable approach!